# Facebook iOS SDK - Facebook App Crashes on openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions. My App Hangs on Login

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-login

I really need some help here:

Sometimes (I Can't seem to reproduce it 100%), when I Execute:

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"read_friendlists", @"user_photos", @"user_events", nil];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
//...

                                  }];
```

Facebook App Opens Up and then Crashes, Sending NO RESPONSE to My App.

My App then Hangs on "Logging in..." and Is STUCK from that Point on.

I Know the FB APP is not my responsibility, but this is giving us a big head-ache here and I'm wondering what is the best way to deal with this. Should I Create a "Time-Out" Mechanism for the Facebook Login and after that Time-Out My App will re-attempt or prompt the User for an Email Login?

Has anyone dealt with this already?

Any Tips?

Thanks